# Working of numpy array to torch tensor conversion

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I want to know how the conversion from a NumPy array to a tensor happens in PyTorch as well as Tensorflow. Does it create a copy of the entire array or there is some in-place mechanism?

Secondly, how to clear the memory that was used earlier by the NumPy array that was later converted into a tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When device is CPU in PyTorch, PyTorch and Numpy uses the same internal representation of n-dimensional arrays in memory, so when converted from a Numpy array to a PyTorch tensor no copy operation is performed, only the way they are represented internally is changed. [Refer here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#bridge-with-numpy).
2. Python garbage collector uses reference counts for clearing unused memory similar to shared pointers in C++.